# External call data preview showing headers and status but not response body

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, geocoding

Using the external call action to geocode address data using the geocodio api

The GET request is returning a 200 Okay response and I can see in the geocodio portal that at least one result is being returned for each call. However, the data preview in data flows is only returning the headers and status as columns, not the body. I believe my selections are correct so what am I doing wrong?

relative_geocode_url is just a derived column which contains the correct relative url for each row

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this, the solution is that the JSON Schema has to be explicitly provided in the type field of the body but also in a format preferred by ADF.

For example a response body like this
`{"input":{"a":1,"b":2}, "result":3"}`

has to be rewritten in the body type as `(input as (a as integer, b as integer), result as integer)`

I was misled pursuing consistency in ADF. This only seems to the case when rest calls are used as a subsequent step in a data flow. I have used rest calls as source and ADF/Data flows infers the body schema from the response without being told explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the headers also.Since I have no clue as to how is the internal API is returning the data and since you have a status code of 200, I am inclined to to try different JSON setting .

I always use curl or postman to check the API responses , before trying the same in data flow/ADF  .

Comment: this is not the form of an answer it should be a comment on the OP